# Derivation of Derangement in Permutations and Combinations

Tags: permutations, recursion

let me start by defining a function $D(n)$ for Derangement of $n$ distinct items.

if there are n distinct items, they can be arranged in $n!$ different ways.

so , $$ D(n) = n! - (\binom{n}{1}D(n-1) + \binom{n}{2}D(n-2) + \binom{n}{3}D(n-3) + .... + \binom{n}{n-n}D(n-n))$$

I have substracted all number of **ways** in which *1 , 2 , 3 ... ,n* items are on its place and no other item is on its place.

is there any way to solve it further solve this equation and get it as a function of n only ?

Comment: The standard literature contains many derivations of the count of derangements, including by Inclusion-Exclusion.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) for example.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. 